# Defining function with more than 2 ranges in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to create probability density function in R as in the picture below

[image: My propability density function]

```
k = 1
ff = function(x)
{
  ifelse( x > 1, k,0)
}
f = function(x){
  scale  = integrate(ff,0,8);
  ff(x) / scale$value
}
a = f(5)
```

The code above works fine. But when I try to check if x is between 0 and 7, or have more than one statement of `ifelse()` (Happens also with normal if statement)

```
k = 1
ff = function(x)
{
  ifelse(x < 7 && x > 1, k,0)
}
f = function(x){
  scale  = integrate(ff,0,8);
  ff(x) / scale$value
}
a = f(5)
```

I get such error:

```
Error in integrate(ff, 0, 8) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

How can I model function with more than 2 ranges?

Comment: Use single `&`, `ifelse(x < 7 & x > 1, k,0)`

Comment: That function is not the function in the graph. Function `ff` is a uniform density in [1, 7].